# Blazor CascadingParameter is always null

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

New to Blazor, having trouble getting a `CascadingParameter` to populate from my `MainLayout.razor`:

```
@code
{
    private Toasts Toasts { get; set; }
}
        
<Toasts @ref="@Toasts" />
    
<CascadingValue Value="Toasts">
    @Body
</CascadingValue>
```

And `Index.razor` page:

```
[CascadingParameter]
public Toasts Toasts { get; set; }

public async Task PackageChanged(string value)
{
   Toasts.Something(value); //Toasts is null here
}
```

And finally Toasts.razor:

```
@code {

    private string Message { get; set; }

    public void Something(string message)
    {
        Message = message;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
}

@Message
```

This code below frustratingly works, but I'd like to cascade just the one component (`<Toasts />`) instead of the whole layout:

```
<CascadingValue Value="@this">
    <Toasts @ref="@Toasts" />
    @Body
</CascadingValue>
```

And then index:

```
[CascadingParameter]
public MainLayout Layout { get; set; }

 public async Task PackageChanged(string value)
 {
      Layout.Toasts.Something(value); //this behaves as expected
 }
```

Comment: Just throwing spaghetti at the wall, but how about initializing an instance: `public Toasts Toasts { get; set; } = new Toasts();`  Also, in `Index`, `Toasts.Something();` provides no string, where as in `Toasts.razor`, it requires a message.  That's not gonna work, and I'm surprised if it even compiles.

Comment: I don't think a new Instance will be different than the one rendered.  How are you checking the Guid property?  Since `OnItialized` runs twice, I think it's more likely that you're seeing your Guid change between two passes and getting confused by that.

Comment: I was checking it with my debugger, index.razor instance had a different guid than the one rendered. I've since realized this probably isnt a good check, so now I'm just displaying the string (`@Message`), see my latest update. I dont understand why I'd have to new it up, why wouldnt it just use the instance of Toasts in the markup?  Isnt that what @ref is for?

Comment: Yeah, that's why I called it throwing spaghetti at the wall-- I hadn't seen your code yet, so I was guessing.  I'm a little concerned about the `private` access in your layout code.  I don't know how that will play out, but I'm suspicious of it.

Comment: I've tried protected and public, didnt change anything.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973, I usually agree with you, but this time you're wrong. You should never instantiate a component as if it was a normal class. Components are always instantiated by Blazor.

Comment: I can confirm that I'm wrong about almost everything I said.  The `new()` did make a passable reference, but calls to its `Something()` method didn't render, so it does look like a separate instance.  Without creating a new instance, the code compiled but crashed.  The only way I could get it to work was to pass the entire Layout object as `this` and then refer to `Toast` through it.  I've definitely passed references to Component objects before and it worked, but I'd have to dig up the code to see in what context I did it-- it for sure wasn't in a Layout page.

Comment: @mxmissile, Sorry, but this is not possible, as you're trying to send a reference to a child component before the rendering cycle completes, and the child component has not yet created. You can't pass a component reference... Design your code to pass a class value which is not a component instead.

Comment: Note my new answer. It is working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is working for me

### MainLayout...partial code

```
<div class="main">
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <Toasts @ref="Toasts" />
        </div>

        @if (Toasts != null)
        {
            <CascadingValue Value="@Toasts">
                @Body
            </CascadingValue>
        }
 </div>

@code
{
    protected Toasts Toasts;

    protected override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
 }
```

The following solution, in which we cascade a reference to MainLayout, and then retrieve a reference to the Toasts component, is a bit more effective than the one above, as it does not require the MainLayout to render a second time.

### MainLayout...partial code

```
<div class="main">
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <Toasts @ref="Toasts" />
        </div>

         <CascadingValue Value="this">
            @Body
         </CascadingValue>     
 </div>

@code
{
    public Toasts Toasts { get; set; }
 }
```

### Index.razor

```
@page "/"

@code{
   
    [CascadingParameter]
    public MainLayout Layout { get; set; }
    
   
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        // Reference the Toasts component's methods and properties
        // Note: You must not pass parameter values to the Toasts
        // component from here. You'll get a warning, or perhaps 
        // an error.
 
        Layout.Toasts.Something("Pass a message to the 
                                Something method");
    }

}
```

Comment: This worked, however VS said I didnt need the null check. Thanks for everyone's help. I'm wondering though, is it wrong to pass a referenced Component like that? Should I just use a service instead?

Comment: Right, so we CAN pass component object references, but with care.  I have to say, though, after all this, I'd prefer just to pass the entire layout object anyway-- I feel it's easier to track where the `[CascadingParameter]` comes from-- you want access to something on the layout markup, so you pass the layout object, and it's crystal clear when you return to your code 6 months what you were up to.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973:   `I'd prefer just to pass the entire layout object anyway.` I often disagree with you, but not this time. Yes, it is a bit better to send a reference to the MainLayout itself... but not from the reason you mention. I've added a new version to my answer to accomodate for your desires...

Comment: @enet that was actually a comment to the OP.  Several posts, including your working answer, came AFTER the OP discovered they could pass the layout object, and them saying they really just wanted to pass the `Toasts` object.  Let me rephrase then: "enet has correctly solved the problem as described in the OP question, but I don't actually think the OP's desired method is the preferable one."

Answer (score 1):

This statement in MainLayout.razor do not work

```
<Toasts @ref="@Toasts" />
```

But this statement works and cascading parameter in index.razor is not null

```
@code
{
    private Toasts Toasts= new();
}
```

Seems that Blazor do not allow to pass element references as cascading parameter but only allows object and other variables. I do not have full context of your requirements, but you can try implementing Toasts as a service.

Comment: You must not new up a component... A component differs from a normal class, and it is always created by the framework, not by the developer. At best, you can capture a reference to a component, but this is not possible in the current context.

Comment: Yes its right I just new up to draw attention that Blazor do not allow to pass component references as cascading parameters but only other variables

Comment: `Blazor do not allow to pass component references as cascading parameters` That's not true. You can pass `this`, which is a reference to the MainLayout component, but you can't capture a reference to the  `Toasts` component from within the MainLayout component.

Comment: What I mean is Toasts has a valid value in MainLayout but its not travelling to child components