# CascadingValue is sometimes null in the inner component

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

Here's my MainLayout.razor

```cs
    <div style="height: 100%; overflow-y: hidden;">
        <div style="margin: 0; height: 100%; overflow-y: hidden;">
            <div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100%; overflow-y: hidden;">
                <div style="flex-grow: 1; width: 100%; overflow: auto;">
                    <div style="height: 100%; overflow: auto;">
                        <main>
                            <div class="my-main-scrollbar">
                                <CascadingValue Value=PopupMessageBox>
                                    @Body
                                </CascadingValue>
                            </div>
                        </main>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<PopupMessageBox @ref="PopupMessageBox" />
```

And here's the key part of MainLayout.razor.cs

```cs
    public partial class MainLayout
    {
        public PopupMessageBox PopupMessageBox { get; private set; } = default!;
        //...
```

Then in my inner component I have

```cs
    [CascadingParameter]
    private PopupMessageBox PopupMessageBox { get; set; } = default!;
```

And this is rarely null at the start of `OnInitializedAsync()`. But if I then reload the page via the browser - it's null. It however is not null by the time `OnAfterRenderAsync()` fires.

There are answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63944166/outermost-cascadingvalue-is-lost-on-page-refresh-or-direct-link) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71773637/blazor-cascadingparameter-is-always-null) but they don't make sense to me. It seems to be that this is passed as a `Task<something>` and I need to await it. Which makes sense. But hwo do I do that for an object? Everything I tried for that would not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@HH has already identified the cause. The problem is your not in control of the render process, and what gets rendered when.  In your code you're often cascading `default!` which is `null`.

There are several ways to code this.  HH has suggested one in his answer.

Here's a very basic demo:

A demo component that contains the popup code and cascades itself.

```cs
<CascadingValue Value="this" IsFixed>
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

@*Put you popup code here*@

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

    // Code to open/close the popup
}
```

**MainLayout**

```
        <article class="content px-4">
            <Component1>
                @Body
            </Component1>
        </article>
```

And a demo `Index` to show it's never null at cascade time:

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private Component1 PopUp { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(PopUp);
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

However, I have an issue with cascading components: I don't think it's good practice in general.  Your passing an object with a lot of functionality (and baggage) that isn't relevant in the context (it's a code smell!).  I prefer to split out the context/state from the component, and cascade a context object like this:

```
public class PopUpContext
{
    public Func<Task<bool>> ShowAsync { get; private set; }

    public bool IsDisplayed { get; private set; }

    public PopUpContext(Func<Task<bool>> showAsync)
        => ShowAsync = showAsync;

    public void SetAsDisplayed(bool value)
        => this.IsDisplayed = value;
}
```

My `PopUp` Demo component setting up and cascading the context.

```cs
@if (_popUpContext.IsDisplayed)
{
    <h3>Component1</h3>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick=Close>Close</button>
}

<CascadingValue Value=_popUpContext IsFixed=true>
    @ChildContent
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }
    private TaskCompletionSource<bool> _taskCompletionSource = new();
    private PopUpContext _popUpContext;

    public PopUp()
        => _popUpContext = new PopUpContext(this.ShowAsync);

    public Task<bool> ShowAsync()
    {
        _popUpContext.SetAsDisplayed(true);
        StateHasChanged();
        _taskCompletionSource = new();
        return _taskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        _popUpContext.SetAsDisplayed(false);
        StateHasChanged();
        _taskCompletionSource.SetResult(true);
    }
}
```

And my quick Demo page:

```
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<div class="m-2">
    <button class="btn btn-dark" @onclick=Show>Open</button>
</div>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter] private PopUpContext _popUpContext { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(_popUpContext);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task Show()
        => await _popUpContext.ShowAsync.Invoke();
}
```

Comment: Would MainLayout then be <Popup>@Body</Popup>? If so, this is weird to me that the popup then is a containing component of all the pages. Would I be better off sticking with what I have and never calling Popup until in/after OnAfterRenderAsync(true)? Or should I not view this as weird? thanks

Comment: Yes. Consider what you have - You're wrapping the body in a `CascadingValue`.  What do you think a `CascadingValue` is?  Yes a little weird, creating a base wrapper component [with the code within the wrapper which you inherit] is more elegant, but [as I've said before] you are constrained by the `ComponentBase` design cage.  The alternative is to only add the component to pages where you need it and use a `@ref`.  Building a system where you can only do "normal stuff" in `OnAfterRenderAsync` is bad design.   Coding components is different!

Comment: Once again I defer to your judgement - I'll try this. And yes that does make sense, by definition a cascading value is something the code is within.

Comment: Just implemented this - super easy to do (thank you for a great example) and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The cause looks clear: `@Body` is rendered before `<PopupMessageBox @ref="PopupMessageBox" />`. So it depends on the async rendering behind @Body what will happen. I expect that a second render will be less async due to caching and therefore yield `null` more often.

It would be more reliable to pass in the MainLayout itself, maybe behind an interface like IPopupManager:

```
   <CascadingValue Value='this' IsFixed='true' >
        @Body
    </CascadingValue>
```

Comment: There are times, like here, where I wish I could select two answers as the accepted answer. I think your solution is a good approach too.

Comment: Although wouldn't the root problem remain? It can call up to the MaisLayout.PopupManager no problem, but in MainLayout PopupMessageBox is null there and so I would still get the null pointer exception. Or wouldn't I?

Comment: I think that in OnInitialzed of a Page you could still see a NULL there. It will always be a matter of timing. But you don't want a popup before you have rendered the page.

Comment: This is a popup (DxPopup) that is async so fundamentally all I'm doing is setting some properties in it (header & message) and setting it to Visible. I think it will then, if I have the pointer, just render with everything else as it renders. But that brings up a question that I'd like your opinion on. cont...

Comment: The use case for this is I have a try/catch in OnInitializedAsync() and if anything unexpected happens, I then populate and show the error in the popup in the catch. For this use case, should I save off the header/message and then set the properties & make the popup visible in OnAfterRenderAsync(). Not asking in terms of what's easier/better for the CascadingValue, but asking in general terms of where it's appropriate to do this. TIA